# Make text at bottom of div

Tags: css, html

How can i make a text stick at the bottom of a div. i tried this:

```
dd{
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

but it doesn't work.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdxucte6/)

Comment: try `position:absolute`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `position: absolute;`

You have to set the parent div to something else than `position: static;` like `position: relative;`

Comment: it works, i set the element to position: absolute; and the parent to  position: relative;

Answer (score 0):

Change your `relative` position to `absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

you have a error in your sintaxis you miss the `'px'` in the `bottom` property and the `height` to be referenced, the `position` can be relative or not depend of the location of your object

```
 dd{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 210px;
}
```

this is the correct code:
**<kbd>[Live CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/gdxucte6/3/)</kbd>** http://jsfiddle.net/gdxucte6/3/